# Unable to Create Docker Image for puppeteer

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a docker image using the [docker file](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile)

```
FROM node:18

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-khmeros fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -rm -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser

USER pptruser

WORKDIR /home/pptruser

COPY puppeteer-browsers-latest.tgz puppeteer-latest.tgz puppeteer-core-latest.tgz ./

# Install @puppeteer/browsers, puppeteer and puppeteer-core into /home/pptruser/node_modules.
RUN npm i ./puppeteer-browsers-latest.tgz ./puppeteer-core-latest.tgz ./puppeteer-latest.tgz \
    && rm ./puppeteer-browsers-latest.tgz ./puppeteer-core-latest.tgz ./puppeteer-latest.tgz \
    && (node -e "require('child_process').execSync(require('puppeteer').executablePath() + ' --credits', {stdio: 'inherit'})" > THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES)

CMD ["google-chrome-stable"]
```

But I don't have these .tgz files in my working directory 
`puppeteer-browsers-latest.tgz puppeteer-latest.tgz puppeteer-core-latest.tgz`

So the image is not getting created . Where can I get the .tgz files for puppeteer ? 
I tried running npm pack inside puppeteer module to create the .tgz file but ran into error `wireit` not recognised. After installing wireit it gave error `cp` not recognised.

How do I sucessfully create a docker image using the above docker file ?

Answer (score 1):

Going through this [issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9337#issuecomment-1330163766) I tried to install puppeteer instead of using those .tgz files and modified the dockerfile and was able to create the docker image.

```
FROM node:18

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-khmeros fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -rm -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser

USER pptruser

RUN npm i puppeteer \
    && (node -e "require('child_process').execSync(require('puppeteer').executablePath() + ' --credits', {stdio: 'inherit'})" > THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES)

CMD ["google-chrome-stable"]
```